# Not able to update the value input field after fetching data from json-server in react js

Tags: reactjs, input, fetch, updates, json-server

Hii Everyone i tried to update my data after fetching from json-server but not I am not able to do it.

help me out guys.

Here is the code:-

```
 import React from "react"; 
import  {  useEffect, useState } from "react"; 
import './cssfiles/newscenario.css';

import {  useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const EditScenario = ()=>{ 
const {sc_id} = useParams();
 // console.log(sc_id) 
let Navigate = useNavigate(); 
const [validation, valchange] = useState(false); 
const [validate, valichange] = useState(false);

 const [name, namechange] = useState("");
  const [time, timechange] = useState("");
 
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/scenario/" +sc_id).then((res)=>{
      return res.json();
    }).then((resp)=>{
      namechange(resp.name)
      timechange(resp.time)
    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err.message);
    })
  });


 const insertscenario = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   let inobj = { name, time  };
   fetch(" http:localhost:8000/scenario"+sc_id, {
     method: "PUT",
     headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
     body: JSON.stringify(inobj)
   }).then((res) => {
    alert("Saved Sucessfully")
     console.log(inobj);
   }).catch((err) => {
     console.log(err.message);
   });
   
 }
const error = ()=>{
    if(name.length===0 && time.length===0 ){
      valchange(true);
      valichange(true);
      
    }

   }

 
  const emptyfield = () =>{
    namechange('');
    timechange('');
  }
return(
    <div>
   <div className="addscenario">
  <p className="para">Scenario/Edit</p>
  <h1>Edit Scenario</h1>
  <form className="add_inp" >
    <div className="scenario_name">
      
      <label for = "name" className="label">Scenario Name</label>
      
      <input name="name"    type="text" value={name}  onMouseDown={e => { valchange(true) }} onChange={e => { namechange(e.target.value) }} className="newscenario" placeholder="Scenario Name" />
        {name.length===0 && validation && <span required  name="name" className="error1">Scenario is required </span>}
    </div>
    <div className="scenario_time">
      <label for = "time" className="label">Scenario Time(seconds)</label>
      <input name="time"  type="number" value={time}  onMouseDown={e => { valichange(true) } } onChange={e => { timechange(e.target.value) }} className="newscenario" placeholder="Scenario Time"  
    />
      {time.length===0 && validate && <span  name="time" className="error">Scenario is required </span>}
      </div>
  </form>
  
     <div className="buttons">
    <button   onClick={insertscenario} className="new_sc">Add</button>
   
    <button onClick={() => Navigate(-1)} className="Prev">Go Back</button>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default EditScenario;

I am Trying to update my data. so i am fectching it in input feild after fetcing data i try to update it but i am not able to change the orignal value.

Comment: What is the purpose of having `useEffect` without dependency array? Do you know how it acts?